# Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement When using Create Table AS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

For a project i need to copy a table from a template, but when executing the SQL code the response is Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

```
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDataB"].ToString();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;


    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE 'TEST' AS SELECT * INTO 'TEST' FROM 
    buttonstemplate";
```

This is the code i have used. Yet when I use an online SQL editor like [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_create_table) It works just fine.
I am using MS Access 2016 and programming in ASP.net

I am just starting to learn to code so I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using

Comment: Microsoft Access

Comment: what happens when you add one more colon for all single colon values like 'TEST' to '''test'''

Comment: Is TEST a variable or actual name you want to assign the table? Did you test the SQL in Access query designer? @TheGameiswar, what colons and where?

Comment: Test is the name of name of the database i want to create, @June7 i did and it gives the same error. but like i said when using the W3school editor it works just fine so i assume its acces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO TEST FROM BUTTONSTEMPLATE
```

To copy table into another database for eg: **externaldb.mdb**

```
SELECT * INTO TEST IN 'externaldb.mdb' FROM BUTTONSTEMPLATE
```

Answer (score 0):

...I don't think that SQL runs fine in [W3 Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_create_table) (like your question said). :-)

[image: w3notworking]

I'm sure you're aware that the first step is to make sure the SQL will run on it's own.

You're combining two different types of SQL statements for creating a table:

`CREATE TABLE` is for defining a new table.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

If you want to create a table based on the results from another table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

...so perhaps you could use:

```
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT * FROM buttonstemplate
```